# making a menu(restaurant menu) in python with the tkinter module

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, menu

using tkinter with python, i am making a menu that shows what you put in. then can be removed by pressing a button, my question is how do i delete the Labels in the right order. the order should be from top to bottom. the "orders" come in by date, the oldest being at the top and the newest being put at the bottom of the list. By using destroy(), i can only manage to delete the very last label(the newest). i need help to figure out how to delete a specific label.

```
#imports-----------------------
from tkinter import *
#from PIL import ImageTk,image
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
#imports----------------------
#start-----------

x=1
height=0
l="0"
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")
#start-----------
def myClick():
    global x    #number of the label
    global height
    global l    #name of the label
    global vartoprint
    global y    #to retain the old value of x
    if x == 1:
        global statehold
        statehold=1
        l=str(statehold)
        vartoprint="order one"
        y=1


    if x > y:           #when x is different than the old value of y, we assume the state has gone up
                        #and therefor a new entry has come, time to print this new value
        height=height+1
        statehold= statehold + 1
        l=str(statehold)
        vartoprint="order 'xxx'"        #in this case, the new value is always "order xxx" for testing

    l = Label(root, text=vartoprint)
    l.grid(row=height, column=L)
    x=x+1

mybutton = Button(root, text="next", padx=10, pady=8, command=myClick, fg="black", bg="white")
mybutton.grid(row=1, column=5)
def mydelete():
    global statehold
    global x
    global l
    statehold= statehold - 1         #tells the system that 1 label  has been removed
    l.destroy()     #destroys the label
    x=x-1           #tells the system that 1 label  has been removed
DeleteButton = Button(root, text="next and delete", command=mydelete)
DeleteButton.grid(row=1, column=6)

#end-------------
time.sleep(3)
root.mainloop()
#end-------------
```

Comment: 2 things: Can you please change the variable names to something that is easier to debug. Second thing: You are only keeping a reference to the last label. You a list and use `<list>.pop(0)` to get the first label and destroy it.

Comment: Also please don't use that many global variables. It is hard to keep track of which variable is which

Comment: hi, thanks for the quick response, i corrected my code for better understanding, how would i use <list>.pop(0) in this context?

Comment: If you use a python list for the labels you can use `pop(0)` to take off the first element of the list. `pop(0)` will return the first label so you can directly call `pop(0).destroy()` to remove the firs label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks using a list and deleting the first list item, i am able to do my task.

I use

```
my_list.append(l)
```

to insert the variable at the end of the list.
and like you said, i use

```
(my_list.pop(0)).destroy()
```

do remove the first item in the list.

thanks, you were great!